# Change BGP Dampening parameters for a specific neighbor

Tags: cisco, bgp

When you configure the BGP Dampening, the configuration is set for all eBGP neighbor in a Cisco router. There is a way to customize the parameters for a specific neighbor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set bgp dampening for an AS path, which accomplishes the same thing.  For example, if your neighbor is AS 1234, you can do something like this:

```
ip as-path access-list 1 permit ^1234

route-map damp_me permit 10
match as-path 1

router bgp 65000
bgp dampening route-map damp_me
```

**Important Note (edited):**

Route dampening recommendations have gone through [several changes](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/clemens_mosig/route-flap-damping-in-the-wild) since first created.  At one point, it was recommended *not* to use it, as it caused more problems than it solved.

Now, [the latest IETF BCP (2015)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp194#section-7) recommends to enable RFD with adjusted values (right-most column), which are different from the vendor defaults.

```
 RFD parameter              Cisco    Juniper   BCP 194 / RIPE-580
 Withdrawal penalty          1000       1000    1000
 Re-advertisement penalty       0       1000    0/1000
 Attributes change penalty    500        500    500
 Suppress-threshold          2000       3000    6000
 Half-life (min)               15         15    15
 Reuse-threshold              750        750    750
 Max suppress time (min)       60         60    60
```

The table is copied from this [article](https://labs.ripe.net/Members/clemens_mosig/route-flap-damping-in-the-wild) which also reports about current deployment and RFD's history.

Comment: The recommendation you shared is not up-to-date. Here is the current version, which actually recommends RFD: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp194#section-7 and https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-580.

Comment: This article reports about current RFD deployment: https://labs.ripe.net/Members/clemens_mosig/route-flap-damping-in-the-wild

Comment: Thanks for the info @cmosig !  I updated my answer.